# Rendering problems to run Android app in Android Studio (V 2.13)

Tags: android-studio, rendering

I am facing rendering problems to run app in Android Studio. Its written:

> tag requires a 'draw able' attribute or child tag defining a draw able.

I am using Android studio version 2.13.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with respect to the background color of a button in android studio.

Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 2.22.00 AM

instead of letting the IDE generate the xml code which was                 " ?android:attire/textColor..... " I just typed in the hex code " #123456 " for the color I wanted. Problem solved.

Comment: well what i found is by editing xml codes solves the problem.